# permission denied even though file is full permisson

Tags: linux, bash

im trying to make an alarm clock like
https://milkteafuzz.com/j/2012/02/22/a-simple-bash-alarm-clock/
but i get permission denied error.
do i have to run a file thats in usr/bin ? i tried that too also didnt work
my code is:

```
 #!/bin/bash
printf "What time are you setting this alarm for? "
read date
echo Okay! Will ring you on $(date --date="$date").
sleep $(( $(date --date="$date" +%s) - $(date +%s) ));
echo Wake up!
 while true; do
 /home/-------/Music/mapleleaf.mp3
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/yehuda/Music/mapleleaf.mp3`?

Comment: You are trying to execute an MP3 file as if it were a program; it is not. You need a program that takes the file as input to play it. (The script you are copying uses `/usr/bin/mpg123`.)

Comment: Please clarify: (1) is there whitespace before `#!` in your file? (2) do you get "permission denied" _immediately_ upon running the script, or only after "Wake up!" is printed? (3) please post the _complete, unedited_ output of `ls -l thenameofthisscript`.

Comment: We can just guess that you are trying to play a .mp3, which you cannot execute in bash. If you want to play it you'll need to use a player program.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a program that will read the mp3 file before the file name on the line in your script.  Any program able to play mp3 files on your system should do the trick.

The permission error comes from the fact that data files (such as your mp3 file) do not (should not) have there "execute" bits set, as they are not programs and cannot be "run" by the OS.  Even the root user will experience the same problem, as it is not an access right issue, but the OS (rightly) refusing to run a file that is not marked as executable.

Activating the mp3 executable bit (which would be done with the `chmod` utility) and then trying to run it would not work, as the contents would obviously not be valid for execution by the OS.

Comment: It wouldn't _crash_.  The OS would still recognize that it is not a valid executable.  You'd get a different, still cryptic, but somewhat more on-point error message, something like `bash: foo.mp3: cannot execute binary file` or `foo.mp3: Exec format error`.

Comment: yes i realized that i had to play the mp3 file with a program like "vlc"            thanks

Answer (score 2):

The script you are copying uses `/usr/bin/mpg123` to play the MP3 file.

```
/usr/bin/mpg123 ~/alarm.mp3
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  program
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
                file to play
```

You have only specified the file to play, which is not a valid command. You need to specify which program to use to play the file (which may require you to first install such a program).